# How to resolve a share HTML & JS code conflict

Tags: javascript, html

```js
 $("#btn-One-time").on( "click", function() {

  $('#don_term_1').click();

  $("#donation-type").val('charge');
  $("#payment_section_cycle").text(' once');

  $('#monthly-options').hide();
  $('#one-time-options').show();

  $('#btn_don').addClass('active');   
  $('#btn_sdn').removeClass('active');

  $('#otherAmountOnetime').removeClass('hidden');  
  $('#otherAmountMonthly').addClass('hidden');

  $('#amount_other').val('');

  clearError(false);
  
 });

 $("#btn-Monthly").on( "click", function() {    

  $('#don_term_4').click();

  $("#donation-type").val('sub');
  $("#payment_section_cycle").text(' per month');

  $('#one-time-options').hide();
  $('#monthly-options').show();

  $('#btn_don').removeClass('active');
  $('#btn_sdn').addClass('active');

  $('#otherAmountOnetime').addClass('hidden');
  $('#otherAmountMonthly').removeClass('hidden');

  clearError(false);  
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controlled_term_selection_section">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 ">

      <div id="custom_donation_grid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
            <div>
              <h4>donation:</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-xs-12 donation-recurring col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
            <button type="button" id="btn_One-time" class="btn btn-lg btn-donation-recurring">One-time</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn_Monthly" class="active btn btn-lg btn-donation-recurring">Monthly</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
            <div>&nbsp;<br>
              <h4>donation:</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="donation-options" class="custom_donation_radios">

          <div id="one-time-options" style="display: none;">
            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" class="amount-total" name="amount" id="don_term_1" value="50">
                <span class="radio_label">
                  <span class="label_text">$50</span>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" class="amount-total" name="amount" id="don_term_2" value="100">
                <span class="radio_label">
                  <span class="label_text">$100</span>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" class="amount-total" name="amount" id="don_term_3" value="250">
                <span class="radio_label">
                  <span class="label_text">$250</span>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="monthly-options">
            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" class="amount-total" name="amount" id="don_term_4" value="10" checked="">
                <span class="radio_label">
                  <span class="label_text">$10</span>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" class="amount-total" name="amount" id="don_term_5" value="15">
                <span class="radio_label">
                  <span class="label_text">$15</span>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" class="amount-total" name="amount" id="don_term_6" value="25">
                <span class="radio_label">
                  <span class="label_text">$25</span>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I have an HTML donation form in one of the pages of the website (let's called donate page) which has JavaScript handle the functionalities and I copy its HTML & JavaScript from that page to use for the pop-up modal form which I use for the header (it applied for every page on the website) because I want it to look like that.

The pop-up modal form function works for every page except for the donate page. Either one of the forms won't work.

My question is how to resolve the share code conflict. I do not want to rename everything to make both forms work.

Comment: Please include code examples.

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow, please try to share some code which helps us to check the validating the code, Thank you

Comment: I added the code to show you but it is just some of the code.

Comment: IDs must be unique on the page. If you're copy-pasting that code, you'll have duplicate IDs.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I understand that is a problem I am facing now. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you don't select the right elements.
I have make those changes

`$("#btn-One-time")` ----> `$("#btn_One-time")`

and

`$("#btn-Monthly")` -----> `$("#btn_Monthly")`

Comment: I have tried it on code snippet. The body of callback function runs. You know that I am not able to test all because you don't post all the code.